# In C turning a char into a string

Tags: c

I am reading from a file using `fgetc` and doing that makes it so that I have a char. However, I want to convert this char to a string such that I can use the `strtok` function upon it. How would I go about doing this?

```
int xp;
while(1) {
    xp = fgetc(filename);
    char xpchar = xp;
    //convert xpchar into a string
}
```

Comment: create a `char` array and start storing into it....what's your question actually?

Comment: A string is just an array of chars with a null character at the end.

Comment: I'm able to print with; printf("%c", xpchar); however I want to use %s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create an array with two items, your character and the null terminator:

```
char str[] = {ch, '\0'};
```

Or if you will, use a compound literal to do the same:

```
(char[]){ch, '\0'}
```

Compound literals can be used to convert your character directly, inside an expression:

```
printf("%s", (char[]){ch, '\0'} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you are going to read not just one character from file, so look at the following example:

```cpp
    #define STR_SIZE 10 
    // STR_SIZE defines the maximum number of characters to be read from file
    int xp;
    char str[STR_SIZE + 1] = { 0 }; // here all array of char is filled with 0
                   // +1 in array size ensure that at least one '\0' char 
                   // will be in array to be the end of string
    int strCnt = 0; // this is the conter of characters stored in the array
    while (1) {
        xp = fgetc(f);
        char xpchar = xp;
        //convert xpchar into a string
        str[strCnt] = xpchar; // store character to next free position of array
        strCnt++;
        if (strCnt >= STR_SIZE) // if array if filled
            break;              // stop reading from file
    }
```

And name of your file-pointer-variable - `filename` looks strange (`filename` is good name for string variable that store name of file, but `fgetc` and `getc` need `FILE *`), so check that in your program you have something like:

```
  FILE * f = fopen(filename, "r");
```

or think over changing name for `filename`.